# Can you display PDFs on a blog in Blogger?

Tags: blogger, pdf

I have a blog about sign language. I would like to post a couple of .pdf pages of my drawn signs put with a song, so people can download.

Is it possible to display a PDF that is a couple of pages on Blogger and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You need to host the PDF files somewhere (eg  https://drive.google.com) that will give you embed code to display the PDF on a website, and then add the embed code to your blog the same way you put any other 3rd-party HTML onto your blog.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sites like https://drive.google.com  https://www.box.com/ for hosting (storing) your pdf files. After uploading your pdf file to these sites, get the HTML embed code of that pdf file and use that HTML code in your Blog post in BLogger.com. Just switch to HTML view while in the blog post editor and paste the HMTL code there :)

Sameer Shamsudeen
India !

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways by using which you can display the PDFs or other documents into your Blogger Blog.Google docs is the most safe and reliable idea to display the document file to the Blog.To display this after you sign in to the Google account,you have to upload a PDF from your system.After clicking on the upload you get a drop down menu which has two options that is File and Folder.After that you select the PDF file open it and upload the document.This process will hardly take two or three minute,but the whole process depends on the speed of the internet.Then share the file and change it to the Public mode and save it.After this process it saves all the changes and upload to the website.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get pdf embed URL from Google drive.

The steps are as follows:

1. Upload the file to Google drive
2. Open the file with drive
3. Go to File>Embed, and then copy the URL from there
4. Then go to blogger and create a new post and then copy the URL code to the HTML code of the post.  Save and you are good to go.

Comment: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/ellipsis.htm

Comment: You mean that you want to include HTML file now